# R function ggplot and lines together doesn't work, sending different warning messages each time

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to plot two different information in one graph. When I use `ggplot` to plot the first dataset it appear correctly. Then I try to add the second dataset using `lines()` and it doesn't appear on the plot.

R is sending two different errors messages depending on whether the plot is created first in the session or I try to plot it second (and further) time:

```
Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet 

Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  invalid graphics state
2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  invalid graphics state
```

When I use "plot" function to plot first dataset and then "lines" to add second dataset it works.
The some is happening i R and in RStudio.
I already:
-used `plot.new()`
-used `dev.off()`
-opened new session
-reinstall `ggplot2`
-reinstall RStudio
-reinstall R and RStudio
-changed datasets - the some is happening on every datasets, even the simplest ones.

```
x1<-c(1:100)
y1<-c(1:100)
y2<-c(50:149)
ymin<-min(y1,y2)
x1y1<-data.frame(x1,y1)
ggplot(x1y1, aes(x1,y1))+geom_line()
lines(x1,y2)
```

Above code results in plotting y1(x1) but y2(x1) doesn't appear and one of the errors is displeyed.

```
plot(x1,y1)
lines(x1,y2)
```

Above code works fine and both datasets are displayed.

I would like to know why `lines()` doesn't work after `ggplot`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to layer the base `plot()` command with `ggplot`. `ggplot` is built so you can layer multiple *geoms* on top of one another.

```
library(ggplot2)
x1 <- c(1:100)
y1 <- c(1:100)
y2 <- c(50:149)
ymin <- min(y1,y2)
x1y1 <- data.frame(x1, y1)
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(x1y1, aes(x1, y1), color = "blue") + 
  geom_line(aes(x = x1, y = y2), color = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the quick answer. When I use your code I get following error and no plot is visible: Error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()` I think there is something wrong with my ggplot2, becouse the suggestion to use ggplot and then lines to add second dataset was used in one EDX courses on R I am attending. However I don't know - I reinstall the package and R and RStudio and nothing changed.

Comment: Wait! When I changed it to : ggplot(x1y1) + 
  geom_line(aes(x1, y1), color = "blue") + 
  geom_line(aes(x = x1, y = y2), color = "red") then it works! Thank you very much!